# Shopify API to enable channel visibility for mobile app in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, api, shopify

I am using shopify's iOS Buy SDK. In that I am creating my product manually by API.

for creating product manually I am passing parameters like :

```
    "published": true,
    "published_scope": "global",
    "publish_on" : today ,
    "published_status": "published",
```

`"published_scope": "global"` should make my product appear/visible/accesible on my shopify's web store and mobile app.

But my product is not visible to my mobile app and web store.

From shopify's Admin portal we make product accessible by Clicking **manage sales channels visibility** and enabling web store and mobile app .

So I want to add the product via API and display it in my mobile app.

Any solution how to achieve this via API and its parameters?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I also having same issue, Thanks in advance

Comment: @Bindi were you able to find a solution ?

Comment: @user427969 , we didn't get any solution at that point because even those guys had not developed that and said in future release they might have the solution for that. We had asked the same question to Shopify Developers - https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Manage-channel-visibility-in-uploading-product-manually/m-p/393803 
You can check there and can also continue in the same thread.

Comment: Thanks @Bindi for the update